# How to textually find an imported name in a module

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I wrote a method called `buildRegex` that, given a name (of type `str`), returns a `regex` object that finds a `from ... import ... name` statement in a `Python` module.

For example, here is the expected behaviour of `buildRegex`:

```
>>> regObj = buildRegex('foo')
>>> regObj.search('from a import fool') is None
True
>>> regObj.search('from a import foo') is not None
True
>>> regObj.search('from a.b.c import foo as food') is None
True
>>> regObj.search('from a.b.c import fool, bar as foo') is not None
True
```

What I have so far works for all the examples above (and more):

```
def buildRegex(name):
    singleImportedName = r'(\b{0}\b(?!\s+as\s+))'.format(name)
    importStatement = r'from\s+(\w+(\.\w+)*)\s+import\s+([^#\n]*)(?={0})'.format(singleImportedName )
    return re.compile(importStatement)
```

`buildRegex` assumes that the searched module has no `SyntaxError`s which is OK.

My problem is, when looking for the imported name `foo`, I also need to know if it is an alias to a different name. I.e. if a module has the statement:

```
from a.b.c import bar as foo
```

I want to know what `foo` is aliasing, in this case, that would be `bar`. Currently, due to `asserted lookaheads` in the regex, that is not possible. So, finally my question:
How can I refactor the regex so that this information is not lost, i.e., if the given name is an alias, then the the name its aliasing is in one of the `regex`'s [groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.groups)?

Comment: The forms are certainly possible to parse using regex, but considering that there might be multiple lines, multiple imports comma separated, etc, are you sure you'd not want to use `ast.parse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast


class Imports(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Import(self, node):
        print("In Import")
        for imp in node.names:
            if imp.asname is not None:
                print("module name = {}, alias = {}".format(imp.name, imp.asname))
            else:
                print("module name = {}".format(imp.name))
        print()

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        print("In ImportFrom")
        for imp in node.names:
            if imp.asname is not None:
                print("module = {}\nname = {}\nalias = {}\nlevel = {}\n".
                      format(node.module, imp.name, imp.asname, node.level))
            else:
                print("module = {}\nname = {}\nlevel = {}\n".
                      format(node.module, imp.name, node.level))
        print()

mod = "temp_test"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))
Imports().visit(p)
```

Input:

```
from bisect import bisect_left as bs
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np

def foo():
    from re import findall

class Foo():
    def test(self):
        from re import compile as cp, finditer as ft
```

Output:

```
In ImportFrom
module = bisect
name = bisect_left
alias = bs
level = 0


In Import
module name = datetime

In Import
module name = time

In Import
module name = numpy, alias = np

In ImportFrom
module = re
name = findall
level = 0


In ImportFrom
module = re
name = compile
alias = cp
level = 0

module = re
name = finditer
alias = ft
level = 0
```

class Import(names)

> An import statement. names is a list of alias nodes.

class ImportFrom(module, names, level)

> Represents from x import y. module is a raw string of the ‘from’ name, without any leading dots, or None for statements such as from . import foo. level is an integer holding the level of the relative import (0 means absolute import).

The [greentreesnakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html#Name) documentation for me at least has a much better explanation of what all the nodes do and how to use the ast module than the actual ast documentation itself.

You can use also pass the module directly or open the py file and pass the content to ast.parse:

```
with open("temp_test.py") as f:
    p = ast.parse(f.read(), filename="<ast>", mode="exec")
Imports().visit(p)
```

And passing the module:

```
import  temp_test

p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(temp_test))
Imports().visit(p)
```

Comment: Both this answer and @Antii 's are good and correct, however this is more correct thanks to the [greentreesnakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html) link which is super helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that instead of writing complicated regular expressions to parse imports, one would actually use the `ast.parse` to parse the source code into abstract syntax tree and find the names from there, as `ast.parse` is guaranteed to parse Python correctly. Something like:

```
import ast

class ImportFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imports = []

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        names = []
        for i in node.names:
            names.append((i.name, i.asname))
        self.imports.append(['import', names])

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        module = node.module
        level = node.level  # how many dots
        names = []
        for i in node.names:
            names.append((i.name, i.asname))

        self.imports.append(('from', level, module, names))

def parse_imports(source):
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    finder = ImportFinder()
    finder.visit(tree)
    return finder.imports
```

Example usage:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(parse_imports('''
from foo import bar, baz, frob
from .. import bar as spam, baz as ham, frob
import bar.baz
import bar.foo as baf
'''))
```

Prints out:

```
[('from', 0, 'foo', [('bar', None), ('baz', None), ('frob', None)]),
 ('from', 2, None, [('bar', 'spam'), ('baz', 'ham'), ('frob', None)]),
 ['import', [('bar.baz', None)]],
 ['import', [('bar.foo', 'baf')]]]
```

The integer on the `from` lines gives the number of `.` before the module name.

Comment: The example output is a bit easier to read if you print array elements in a loop. IE: `parsed_imports = parse_imports('import bar.baz')`, `for imports in parsed_imports: print(imports)`