# How do I find the line and column offsets for imported Python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

I have a class ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037835/3357935)) that uses `ast.NodeVisitor` to get a list of modules imported by a Python file. However, I also want to return the line and column offsets for where the module names are located in the file.

Code:

```
import ast

class ImportFinder(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.imports = []

    def visit_Import(self, node):
        for i in node.names:
            self.imports.append({'import_type': "import", 'module': i.name,})

    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        self.imports.append({'import_type': "from", 'module': node.module})

def parse_imports(source):
    tree = ast.parse(source)
    finder = ImportFinder()
    finder.visit(tree)
    return finder.imports


# Example usage
sample_file = '''
from foo import bar, baz, frob
import bar.baz
import   bar.foo as baf
'''
parsed_imports = parse_imports(sample_file)
for i in parsed_imports:
    print(i)
```

Current output:

```
{'import_type': 'from', 'module': 'foo'}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.baz'}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.foo'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'import_type': 'from', 'module': 'foo', 'line': 2, 'column_offset': 5}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.baz', 'line': 3, 'column_offset': 7}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.foo', 'line': 4, 'column_offset': 9}
```

How do I get the line and column offsets for imported Python module names?

Comment: The syntax tree doesn't keep that info.  Have you considered doing this by hand?  `from` and `import` are the first non-space words on the line.  You'd just have to check for triple-quotes.

Comment: I'd considered searching for the matched module name, although I was hopeful there would be a built-in method.

Comment: `import` and `from` do not have to be at the beginning of a file. You can parse then unparse to get rid of line continuations (backslashes) and what not. If you need such information, use [libcst](https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this as a starting point.  It doesn't handle continuation lines, but it would be a Machiavellian coder who wrote:

```
import \
    os
```

You could handle that by using a filter function to combine the continuations and yield the longer lines.

```
import re

def parse_imports(source):
    hits = []
    source = re.sub(r"'''[\']'''","",source)
    source = re.sub(r'"""[\"]"""',"",source)
    for no,line in enumerate(source.splitlines()):
        ls = line.lstrip()
        if ls.startswith( "from " ):
            p1 = ls.split()
            mod = p1[1].rstrip()
            i1 = line.find(mod)
            hits.append({
                "import_type": p1[0],
                "module": mod,
                "line": no+1,
                "column_offset": i1
            })
        elif ls.startswith( "import" ):
            cl = ls.split(',')
            p1 = cl[0].split()
            for mod in  [p1[1]] + [c.strip().split()[0] for c in cl[1:]]:
                i1 = line.find(mod)
                hits.append({
                    "import_type": p1[0],
                    "module": mod,
                    "line": no+1,
                    "column_offset": i1
                })
    return hits

# Example usage
sample_file = '''
from foo import bar, baz, frob
import bar.baz
import   bar.foo as baf
import  os,re,  sys
'''
parsed_imports = parse_imports(sample_file)
for i in parsed_imports:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{'import_type': 'from', 'module': 'foo', 'line': 2, 'column_offset': 5}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.baz', 'line': 3, 'column_offset': 7}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'bar.foo', 'line': 4, 'column_offset': 9}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'os', 'line': 5, 'column_offset': 8}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 're', 'line': 5, 'column_offset': 11}
{'import_type': 'import', 'module': 'sys', 'line': 5, 'column_offset': 16}
```

Note -- I've just noticed a bug here.  I strip out all triple-quoted strings, but I don't compensate for those missing lines in the line count.  That'll be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.10, `AST.alias` objects have line and column attributes. That solves your problem for `import` statements, because the list of imported names in an `import` statement are represented as `AST.alias` objects.

Unfortunately, that doesn't help with `from... import`; in an `ImportFrom` object, the module is an `identifier`, which is a simple string without attributes. (The names imported from the module are `AST.alias` objects, so each of those does have location information. But you want the location of the module name.)

Still, the statement itself has line and column attributes, even earlier than v3.10, and those tell you where the statement starts and ends. So you could use that information to extract a slice consisting only of the `from... import` statement, and then use the [tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/tokenize.html) module to get the second token in the `from... import` statement. (The first token is the `from` keyword.) That's a bit clunky but it's got to be easier and more reliable than trying to attack Python source with regular expressions.